# Is it possible to create a string representation of a lambda in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, lambda

I'm trying to get a toString or something similar of a lambda expression.

For example:
We have this expression

```
val isEvenThan1 = { x: Int ->  
  if (x % 2 == 0) 1
  else 0
}
```

We wan a string output similar to this

```
"(x) -> { if (x % 2 == 0) 1 else 0 }"
```

I'm primarily looking for any libraries or work arounds to be able to output the internal logic of a function.

Comment: You might be able to find a preprocessor or build tool that can do that kind of thing, but at runtime that code will have been compiled to something very different. If you add why you want to do it, people might have some suggestions for ways to go about it